# Codeigniter activerecord selecting null into a dummy column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, dummy-data

I´d like to add an extra column to the select for formatting purposes. The problem is that when I do

```
$this->db->select("NULL as ExtraColumn1")
```

codeigniter treats NULL as a column, so when it generates the query it's something like

```
SELECT `NULL` AS ExtraColumn1 ...
```

which of course returns a DB error. The same happens when I try

```
$this->db->select(" '' as ExtraColumn1")
```

Is there any way of doing it using activerecord?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell CodeIgniter not to wrap fields in ticks. You do this by passing `false` as the second parameter in `select()`:

```
 $this->db->select("NULL as ExtraColumn1", false);
```

From [the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select):

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: @john Conde I use but this is still say error `Unknown column '""' in 'field list'`